# Как удалить символ

Tags: c++, c, строки

Как удалить символ в массиве *сhar с использованием пользовательской функции?

Comment: а что должно произойти после удаления? символ станет пробелом или правая часть строки сдвинется? и как определяем символ? по позиции или по значению?

Comment: Просто удалить. Допустим слово Мама, надо удалить а, в итоге получаем слово Мм.

Comment: По значению, не по позиции.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В C++ вы можете воспользоваться стандартным алгоритмом `std::remove`.Например

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstring>

int main() 
{
    char s[] = "Hello World";

    std::cout << s << std::endl;

    char c = 'o';
    *std::remove( s, s + std::strlen( s ), c )  = '\0';

    std::cout << s << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Вывод программы на консоль

```
Hello World
Hell Wrld
```

В С, а также в C++ вы можете написать свою пользовательскую функцию. Ниже приведена программа на C, но сама функция может использоваться как в программе на C, так и в программе на C++.

```
#include <stdio.h>

char * remove_char( char *s, char c ) 
{ 
    char *q = s; 

    while ( *q && *q != c ) ++q; 

    char *p = q; 

    while ( *q ) 
    { 
        if ( *++q != c ) *p++ = *q; 
    } 

    return s; 
} 

int main(void) 
{
    char s[] = "Hello Wordl";

    puts( s );

    char c = 'o';

    puts( remove_char( s, c ) );

    return 0;
}
```

Вывод программы будет аналогичен, показанному выше, то есть

```
Hello Wordl
Hell Wrdl
```

Comment: Мне надо что бы текст вводил пользователь, а не был созданный.

Comment: @JZ_52 Ну, и вводите текст. Как это связано с вопросом удаления символа в строке?

Answer (score 3):

Ну, раз `char*`, а не `string`...

```
char * delChar(char * s, char q)
{
    for(char * c = s; *c; ++c)
    {
        while(*c == q)
            memmove(c,c+1,strlen(c)+1);
        if (*c == 0) break;
    }
    return s;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    char s[] = "Hello, Dolly!";
    printf("%s\n",s);
    printf("%s\n",delChar(s,'o'));
    printf("%s\n",delChar(s,'!'));
}
```

Сойдет?

Если пугает `memmove`, можо

```
char * delChar(char * s, char q)
{
    for(char * c = s; *c; ++c)
    {
        while(*c == q)
        {
            char * q = c+1;
            while(*(q-1) = *q) ++q;
        }
        if (*c == 0) break;
    }
    return s;
}
```

Можно и за один проход:

```
char * delChar(char * s, char q)
{
    char * c = s, *t = s;
    for(; *t; ++t)
    {
        if (*t != q) *c++ = *t;
    }
    *c = 0;
    return s;
}
```

Comment: А почему лучший вариант последний в списке?

Comment: @avp А чтоб к этому моменту человек разобрался в остальных и смог оценить последний :) Надо было, правда, еще и первые два поменять...